# Jest timeout when unit testing my express controller with async/await

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, jestjs, supertest

So, using supertest and jest, when testing my simple controller I get a timeout message. I'm not sure if I am missing something from the config for jest set-up?

app.ts

```
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import cors from 'cors'
import { UserRoute } from './components/user'

const App = () => {
  const app = express()
  app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }))
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }))
  app.use(cors())

  app.use('/api/auth', UserRoute)

  return app
}

export default App
```

user.controller.ts

```
export const SignUp = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.json({ message: "pass!" });
}
```

user.route.ts

```
import { Router } from 'express'
import { SignUp } from './user.controller'

const router = Router()

router
  .route('/signup')
  .get(SignUp)

export default router
```

user.controller.spec.ts

```
import App from '../../../app'
import supertest from 'supertest'

const request = supertest(App);

describe('Testing user controller', () => {

  it('testing /signup', async () => {
    const res = await request.get("/signup");
    expect(res.body.message).toBe("pass!");
  })
})
```

My jest timeout is 10000, not sure what is missing here for my controller not to return? Potentially to do with async/await?

Comment: Your test is doing a GET request to "/signup" and even when your router is prepare to handle those request, your app is only catching "'/api/auth'" that's why your test do not receive a response

Comment: You're passing an function to superset when it should be an object, so you must call it to make it work `supertest(App())` or unwrap it (highly recommended).

Comment: Thank you @SimonDX, simple miss from myself.. :( passing function to supertest client